# regex start of line anchor alternative

Tags: grep

I have "file.txt" with the following and I need to get only ip addresses that start a line.

I am using gnu utilities for windows and grep seems to be not behaving incorrectly.

```
Random Text Here

ABC 10.0.0.0 - 10.20.0.255

IP                    Ping                  Hostname              

100.5.0.20            11ms             N/S                  

GNU grep 2.5.4

grep -Po ^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3} file.txt

10.0.0.0
10.20.0.255
100.5.0.20
```

Correct behavior should only allow 100.5.0.20 since i specified the start line anchor.

Any other Linux command solutions?

Comment: `grep -Po ^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}` gives me error (because shell tries to interpret unquoted strings)... `grep -Po '^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}'` works correctly for me on both `version 3.4` and `version 2.25`

Comment: just saw you are using windows.. try `grep -Po "^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}"`

Comment: also, you can simplify the regex to `^\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}`

Comment: @Sundeep i was able to try the last command but when i redirect it to notepad it's all gibberish

Comment: I don't use windows, not sure what else could go wrong.. see if `awk '$1 ~ /^[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}$/{print $1}'` works

Answer (score 0):

I ended up improvising,

```
grep -oP "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]{1,3}  " file.txt|  awk "{$1=$1};1" > file.txt
```

This will grab the ip addresses with 2 spaces, and then remove the spaces with awk.

Comment: you can use lookarounds, `(?=  )` instead of piping to awk

Comment: also, just remembered about `^` being a special character in windows, which is why it isn't working for you?

Comment: `grep -oP "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]{1,3}(?=  )"` will work only if the IP is followed by two spaces.. however, lookaround is a zero-width conditional check, it isn't part of the match